# Repeat Numpy array by a sliding window

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sliding-window

From the following array of shape `(6, 3)`:

```py
>>> arr
[
    [1, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 2],
    [1, 2, 0],
    [0, 1, 3],
    [2, 2, 1],
    [2, 0, 2]
]
```

I'd like to repeat the values according to a sliding window of `n=4`, giving a new array of shape `(6-n-1, n, 3)`:

```py
>>> new_arr
[
    [
        [1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 2],
        [1, 2, 0],
        [0, 1, 3]
    ],
    [
        [0, 0, 2],
        [1, 2, 0],
        [0, 1, 3],
        [2, 2, 1]
    ],
    [
        [1, 2, 0],
        [0, 1, 3],
        [2, 2, 1],
        [2, 0, 2]
    ]
]
```

It is relatively straightforward using a loop, but it gets extremely slow with several million values (instead of 6 in this example) in the initial array.

Is there a faster way to get to `new_arr` using Numpy primitives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use NumPy, specifically [this](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html#numpy-lib-stride-tricks-sliding-window-view) function (only NumPy >= 1.20.0):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

new_arr = sliding_window_view(arr, (n, arr.shape[1])).squeeze()
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this using Numpy 1.19 ? For some reason Numpy >= 1.20 has dependency conflicts with TensorFlow.

Comment: `sliding_window_view` is a more user friendly substitute for [`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) introduced in `numpy 1.20`. Just use it with an extreme care.